# Google Coding Challenge Question 2020 : Unspecified Words

Tags: python, string, algorithm

*I got the following problem for the Google Coding Challenge which happened on 16th August 2020. I tried to solve it but couldn't.*

> There are `N` words in a dictionary such that each word is of fixed
> length and `M` consists only of lowercase English letters, that is
> `('a', 'b', ...,'z')`
>  A query word is denoted by `Q`. The length
> of query word is `M`. These words contain lowercase English letters
> but at some places instead of a letter between `'a', 'b', ...,'z'`
> there is `'?'`. Refer to the Sample input section to understand this
> case. 
>  A match count of `Q`, denoted by `match_count(Q)` is the
> count of words that are in the dictionary and contain the same English
> letters(excluding a letter that can be in the position of `?`) in the
> same position as the letters are there in the query word `Q`. In other
> words, a word in the dictionary can contain any letters at the
> position of `'?'` but the remaining alphabets must match with the
> query word.
>
> You are given a query word Q and you are required to compute
> `match_count`.
>
> **Input Format**
>
> - The first line contains two space-separated integers `N` and `M` denoting the number of words in the dictionary and length of each word
>   respectively.
> - The next `N` lines contain one word each from the dictionary.
> - The next line contains an integer Q denoting the number of query words for which you have to compute match_count.
> - The next `Q` lines contain one query word each.
>
> **Output Format**  
>  For each query word, print `match_count` for a specific word in a new line. 
> **Constraints**
>
> ```
> 1 <= N <= 5X10^4
> 1 <= M <= 7 
> 1 <= Q <= 10^5
> ```

[image]

[image]

[image]

So, I got 30 minutes for this question and I could write the following code which is incorrect and hence didn't give the expected output.

```
def Solve(N, M, Words, Q, Query):
    output = []
    count = 0
    for i in range(Q):
        x = Query[i].split('?')
        for k in range(N):
            if x in Words:
               count += 1
            else:
                pass
        output.append(count)
    return output

N, M = map(int , input().split())
Words = []
for _ in range(N):
    Words.append(input())

Q = int(input())
Query = []
for _ in range(Q):
    Query.append(input())

out =  Solve(N, M, Words, Q, Query)
for x in out_:
    print(x)
```

*Can somebody help me with some pseudocode or algorithm which can solve this problem, please?*

Comment: Wouldn't the obvious algorithm be "for each Query, for each Word, for each letter in the Query, if the letters are the same or a question mark, then count+=1"?

Comment: I'm struggling to think of an improvement on the obvious algorithm that doesn't take a massive amount of memory. So far I have N+2^M memory for precomputed bitfields, and N+M! memory for precomputed tries.

Comment: Yes, count+=1!! But I gotta keep track of the place of the letter. Also, multiple '?' can be there in a query.

Comment: One could use N*M extra memory to make the obvious query ~26x faster, I suppose, by tracking only one letter per word instead of full bitfields...

Comment: "Multiple ? can be there in a query" That's not a problem if you compare each letter one at a time.  Don't use split.

Comment: Ummmm... I don't understand how

Comment: I assume "replace `?` with `.` and use it as a regular expression" would not be fast enough for the dictionary size and number of queries?

Comment: Yes, regular expression does seem like a good idea. Let me try it out

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I guess my first try would have been to replace the `?` with a `.` in the query, i.e. change `?at` to `.at`, and then use those as regular expressions and match them against all the words in the dictionary, something as simple as this:

```
import re
for q in queries:
    p = re.compile(q.replace("?", "."))
    print(sum(1 for w in words if p.match(w)))
```

However, seeing the input sizes as N up to 5x10<sup>4</sup> and Q up to 10<sup>5</sup>, this might be too slow, just as any other algorithm comparing all pairs of words and queries.

On the other hand, note that `M`, the number of letters per word, is constant and rather low. So instead, you could create Mx26 sets of words for all letters in all positions and then get the intersection of those sets.

```
from collections import defaultdict
from functools import reduce

M = 3
words = ["cat", "map", "bat", "man", "pen"]
queries = ["?at", "ma?", "?a?", "??n"]

sets = defaultdict(set)
for word in words:
    for i, c in enumerate(word):
        sets[i,c].add(word)

all_words = set(words)
for q in queries:
    possible_words = (sets[i,c] for i, c in enumerate(q) if c != "?")
    w = reduce(set.intersection, possible_words, all_words)
    print(q, len(w), w)
```

In the worst case (a query that has a non-`?` letter that is common to most or all words in the dictionary) this may still be slow, but should be much faster in filtering down the words than iterating all the words for each query. (Assuming random letters in both words and queries, the set of words for the first letter will contain N/26 words, the intersection for the first two has N/26² words, etc.)

This could probably be improved a bit by taking the different cases into account, e.g. (a) if the query does not contain any `?`, just check whether it is in the `set` (!) of words without creating all those intersections; (b) if the query is all-`?`, just return the set of all words; and (c) sort the possible-words-sets by size and start the intersection with the smallest sets first to reduce the size of temporarily created sets.

About time complexity: To be honest, I am not sure what time complexity this algorithm has. With N, Q, and M being the number of words, number of queries, and length of words and queries, respectively, creating the initial sets will have complexity O(N*M). After that, the complexity of the queries obviously depends on the number of non-`?` in the queries (and thus the number of set intersections to create), and the average size of the sets. For queries with zero, one, or M non-`?` characters, the query will execute in O(M) (evaluating the situation and then a single set/dict lookup), but for queries with two or more non-`?`-characters, the first set intersections will have on average complexity O(N/26), which strictly speaking is still O(N). (All following intersections will only have to consider N/26², N/26³ etc. elements and are thus negligible.) I don't know how this compares to The Trie Approach and would be very interested if any of the other answers could elaborate on that.

Comment: I added code for the regex approach, too, but I doubt that this will execute within the time limit.

Comment: I have never used reduce and defaultdict in python... Will try to go through it.. But it works smoothly.. Thanks!

Comment: how does the time complexity of this algorithm compare against the trie approach?

Comment: @Alireza Since I see no single "the" Trie approach, but just several answers that say to use a Trie and then drop a huge blob of code without any explanation, you might better ask them.

Answer (score 8):

This question can be done by the help of Trie Data Structures.
First add all words to trie ds.
Then you have to see if the word is present in trie or not, there's a special condition of ' ?' So you have to take care for that condition also, like if the character is ? then simply go to next character of the word.

I think this approach will work, there's a similar Question in Leetcode.

Link : https://leetcode.com/problems/design-add-and-search-words-data-structure/

Answer (score 2):

It should be O(N) time and space approach given M is small and can be considered constant. You might want to look at implementation of Trie here.

Perform the first pass and store the words in Trie DS.

Next for your query, you perform a combination of DFS and BFS in the following order.

If you receive a ?, Perform BFS and add all the children.
For non ?, Perform a DFS and that should point to the existence of a word.

For further optimization, a suffix tree may also be used for storage DS.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a simplified version of trie as the query string has pre-defined length. No need of `ends` variable in the Trie node

```cpp
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

typedef struct TrieNode_ {
    struct TrieNode_* nxt[26];
} TrieNode;

void addWord(TrieNode* root, string s) {
    TrieNode* node = root;
    for(int i = 0; i < s.size(); ++i) {
        if(node->nxt[s[i] - 'a'] == NULL) {
            node->nxt[s[i] - 'a'] = new TrieNode;
        }
        node = node->nxt[s[i] - 'a'];
    }
}

void matchCount(TrieNode* root, string s, int& cnt) {
    if(root == NULL) {
        return;
    }
    if(s.empty()) {
        ++cnt;
        return;
    }
    TrieNode* node = root;
    if(s[0] == '?') {
        for(int i = 0; i < 26; ++i) {
            matchCount(node->nxt[i], s.substr(1), cnt);
        }
    }
    else {
        matchCount(node->nxt[s[0] - 'a'], s.substr(1), cnt);
    }
}

int main() {
    int N, M;
    cin >> N >> M;
    vector<string> s(N);
    TrieNode *root = new TrieNode;
    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
        cin >> s[i];
        addWord(root, s[i]);
    }
    int Q;
    cin >> Q;
    for(int i = 0; i < Q; ++i) {
        string queryString;
        int cnt = 0;
        cin >> queryString;
        matchCount(root, queryString, cnt);
        cout << cnt << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more how this works? If I understand the code correctly, when a `?` is encountered you would check all the branches of the Trie. But this means, that for a query like `????x` you would basically explore the entire Trie, right? I might be missing something, but I think the Set-approach is a bit like the Trie, except it can dive right into the `x` (or generally the most-restricting character) and ignore all the `?`, am I right?

Comment: @tobias_k I think you are right. In worst case a query like ??????? could take 26^7 = 8*10^9 time complexity. And this is for just one such query. For Q queries it won't be feasible

Comment: @tobias_k The code does precisely what you described. The set approach is indeed like a trie for the largest prefix until we get `?`. Trie approach would work fine for small `M`. It also saves the overhead of finding set intersections. 
PS: Now I feel bad that I didn't practice cp in python :/.

Answer (score 1):

Notes: 1. This code doesn't read the input but instead takes params from main method.
2. For large inputs, we could use java 8 streams to parallelize the search process and improve the performance.

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class WordSearch {

private void matchCount(int N, int M, int Q, String[] words,  String[] queries) {
    
    Pattern p = null;
    Matcher m = null;
    int count = 0;
    
    for (int i=0; i<Q; i++) {
        
        p = Pattern.compile(queries[i].replace('?','.'));
        for (int j=0; j<N; j++) {
            m = p.matcher(words[j]);
            if (m.find()) {
                count++;    
            }
        }
        System.out.println("For query word '"+ queries[i] + "', the count is: " + count) ;
        count=0;
    }
    System.out.println("\n");
    
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    WordSearch ws = new WordSearch();
    int N = 5; int M=3; int Q=4;
    String[] w = new String[] {"cat", "map", "bat", "man", "pen"};
    String[] q = new String[] {"?at", "ma?", "?a?", "??n" };
    ws.matchCount(N, M, Q, w, q); 
    
    w = new String[] {"uqqur", "1xzev", "ydfgz"}; 
    q = new String[] {"?z???", "???i?", "???e?", "???f?", "?z???"};
    N=3; M=5; Q=5;
    ws.matchCount(N, M, Q, w, q);
    
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

I would create a lookup table for each letter of each word, and then use that table to iterate with. While the lookup table will cost O(NM) memory (or 15 entries in the situation shown), it will allow an easy O(NM) time complexity to be implemented, with a best case O(log N * log M).

The lookup table can be stored in the form of a coordinate plane. Each letter will have an "x" position (the letters index) as well as a "y" position (the words index in the dictionary). This will allow a quick cross reference from the query to look up a letter's position for existence and the word's position for eligibility.

Worst case, this approach has a time complexity O(NM) whereby there must be N iterations, one for each dictionary entry, times M iterations, one for each letter in each entry. In many cases it will skip the lookups though.

A coordinate system is also created, which also has O(NM) spacial complexity.

Unfamiliar with python, so this is written in JavaScript which was as close as I could come language wise. Hopefully this at least serves as an example of a possible solution.

In addition, as an added section, I included a heavily loaded section to use for performance comparisons. This takes about 5 seconds to complete a set with 2000 words, 5000 querys, each at a length of 200.

```js
// Main function running the analysis
function run(dict, qs) {

  // Use a coordinate system for tracking the letter and position
  var coordinates = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'.split('').reduce((p, c) => (p[c] = {}, p), {});

  // Populate the system
  for (var i = 0; i < dict.length; i++) {

    // Current word in the given dictionary
    var dword = dict[i];

    // Iterate the letters for tracking
    for (var j = 0; j < dword.length; j++) {

      // Current letter in our current word
      var letter = dword[j];

      // Make sure that there is object existence for assignment
      coordinates[letter][j] = coordinates[letter][j] || {};

      // Note the letter's coordinate by storing its array 
      // position (i) as well as its letter position (j)
      coordinates[letter][j][i] = 1;
    }
  }

  // Lookup the word letter by letter in our coordinate system
  function match_count(Q) {

    // Create an array which maps from the dictionary indices 
    // to a truthy value of 1 for tracking successful matches
    var availLookup = dict.reduce((p,_,i) => (p[i]=1,p),{});

    // Iterate the letters of Q to check against the coordinate system
    for (var i = 0; i < Q.length; i++) {

      // Current letter in Q
      var letter = Q[i];

      // Skip '?' characters
      if (letter == '?') continue;

      // Look up the existence of "points" in our coordinate system for
      // the current letter
      var points = coordinates[letter];

      // If nothing from the dictionary matches in this position,
      // then there are no matches anywhere and we return a 0
      if (!points || !points[i]) return 0;

      // Iterate the availability truth table made earlier
      // and look up whether any points in our coordinate system
      // are present for the current letter. If they are, then the word
      // remains, if not, it is removed from consideration.
      for(var n in availLookup){
       if(!points[i][n]) delete availLookup[n];
      }
    }

    // Sum the "truthy" 1 values we used earlier to determine the count of
    // matched words
    return Object.values(availLookup).reduce((x, y) => x + y, 0);
  }

  var matches = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < qs.length; i++) {
    matches.push(match_count(qs[i]));
  }
  return matches;
}

document.querySelector('button').onclick=_=>{
console.clear();
var d1 = [
  'cat',
  'map',
  'bat',
  'man',
  'pen'
];
var q1 = [
  '?at',
  'ma?',
  '?a?',
  '??n'
];
console.log('running...');
console.log(run(d1, q1));

var d2 = [
  'uqqur', 
  'lxzev', 
  'ydfgz'
];
var q2 = [
  '?z???', 
  '???i?', 
  '???e?', 
  '???f?', 
  '?z???'
];
console.log('running...');
console.log(run(d2, q2));


// Load it up (try this with other versions to compare with efficiency)
var d3 = [];
var q3 = [];
var wordcount = 2000;
var querycount = 5000;
var len = 200;

var alphabet = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'.split('');
for(var i = 0; i < wordcount; i++){
 var word = "";
 for(var n = 0; n < len; n++){
  var rand = (Math.random()*25)|0;
  word += alphabet[rand];
 }
 d3.push(word);
}
for(var i = 0; i < querycount; i++){
 var qword = d3[(Math.random()*(wordcount-1))|0];
 var query = "";
 for(var n = 0; n < len; n++){
  var rand = (Math.random()*100)|0;
  if(rand > 98){ word += alphabet[(Math.random()*25)|0]; }
  else{ query += rand > 75 ? qword[n] : '?'; }
 }
 q3.push(query);
}

if(document.querySelector('input').checked){
 //console.log(d3,q3);
 console.log('running...');
 console.log(run(d3, q3).reduce((x, y) => x + y, 0) + ' matches');
}
};
```

```html
<input type=checkbox>Include the ~5 second larger version<br>
<button type=button>run</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

I can think of kind of trie with bfs for lookup approach

```
class Node:

def __init__(self, letter):
    self.letter = letter
    self.chidren = {}

@classmethod
def construct(cls):
    return cls(letter=None)

def add_word(self, word):
    current = self

    for letter in word:
        if letter not in current.chidren:
            node = Node(letter)
            current.chidren[letter] = node
        else:
            node = current.chidren[letter]
        current = node

def lookup_word(self, word, m):
    def _lookup_next_letter(_letter, _node):
        if _letter == '?':
            for node in _node.chidren.values():
                q.put((node, i))

        elif _letter in _node.chidren:
            q.put((_node.chidren[_letter], i))

    q = SimpleQueue()
    count = 0
    i = 0
    current = self

    letter = word[i]
    i += 1

    _lookup_next_letter(letter, current)

    while not q.empty():
        current, i = q.get()
        if i == m:
            count += 1
            continue

        letter = word[i]
        i += 1
        _lookup_next_letter(letter, current)

    return count

def __eq__(self, other):
    return self.letter == other.letter if isinstance(other, Node) else other

def __hash__(self):
    return hash(self.letter)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know Python, but the gist of the naive algorithm looks like this:

```
#count how many words in Words list match a single query 
def DoQuery(Words, OneQuery):
    count = 0
    #for each word in the Words list
    for i in range(Words.size()):
        word = Words.at(i)
        #compare each letter to the query
        match = true
        for j in range(word.size()):
            wordLetter = word.at(j)
            queryLetter = OneQuery.at(j)
            #if the letters do not match and are not ?, then skip to next word
            if queryLetter != '?' and queryLetter != wordLetter:
                match = false
                break
        #if we did not skip, the words match. Increase the count
        if match == true
            count = count + 1
    #we have now checked all the words, return the count
    return count
```

Of course, this executes the innermost loop around 3.5x10^10 times, which might be too slow. So one would need to read in the dictionary, precompute some short of shortcut data structure, then use the shortcut to find the answers faster.

One shortcut data structure would be to make a map of possible queries to answers, making the query O(1). There are only 4.47*10^9 possible queries, so this is possibly faster.

A similar shortcut data structure would be to make a trie of possible queries to answers, making the query O(M). There are only 4.47*10^9 possible queries, so this is possibly faster. This is more complex code, but may also be easier to understand for some people.

Another shortcut would be to "assume" each query has exactly one non-question-mark, and make a map of possible queries to subset dictionaries. This would mean you'd still have to run the naive query on the subset dictionary, but it would be ~26x smaller, and thus ~26x faster. You'd also have to convert the real query into only having one non-question-mark to lookup the subset dictionary in the map, but that should be easy.

Comment: Given the possible input size, the inner `if` may execute up to 3.5x10^10 times, which means that the program may not complete in an acceptable time.

Comment: @trincot: That's absolutely correct, but if the OP can't even work out the naive algorithm, then the optimizations are probably beyond them.

Comment: I'll describe optimizations thought.

Comment: @trincot: When N and 27^M are that close together, I'm struggling to think of good optimizations.

Comment: We need a list to be returned by the function

Comment: @NehaChaudhary: This `DoQuery` only does a single query.  You know enough Python to wrap this `DoQuery` function in another function that loops over all the queries, and returns a list.

Answer (score 0):

I think we can use trie to solve this problem.
Initially, we will just add all the strings to the trie, and later when we get each query we can just check whether it exists in trie or not.

The only thing different here is the '?' but we can use it as an all char match, so whenever we will detect the '?' in our search string we will look what are all possible words possible from here and then simply do a dfs by searching the word in all possible paths.

Below is the C++ code

```
class Trie {
public:
bool isEnd;
vector<Trie*> children;
Trie() {
    this->isEnd = false;
    this->children = vector<Trie*>(26, nullptr);
}
};
Trie* root;

void insert(string& str) {
    int n = str.size(), idx, i = 0;
    Trie* node = root;
    while(i < n) {
        idx = str[i++] - 'a';
        if (node->children[idx] == nullptr) {
            node->children[idx] = new Trie();
        }
        node = node->children[idx];
    }
    node->isEnd = true;
}

int getMatches(int i, string& str, Trie* node) {
    int idx, n = str.size();
    while(i < n) {
        if (str[i] >= 'a' && str[i] <='z')
            idx = str[i] - 'a';
        else {
            int res = 0;
            for(int j = 0;j<26;j++) {
                if (node->children[j] != nullptr)
                    res += getMatches(i+1, str, node->children[j]);
            }
            return res;
         }
        
        if (node->children[idx] == nullptr) return 0;
        node = node->children[idx];
        ++i;
    }
    return node->isEnd ? 1 : 0;
}

int main() {
    int n, m;
    cin>>n>>m;
    string str;
    root = new Trie();
    while(n--) {
        cin>>str;
        insert(str);
    }
    int q;
    cin>>q;
    while(q--) {
        cin>>str;
        cout<<(str.size() == m ? getMatches(0, str, root) : 0)<<"\n";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is brute but Trie is a better implemntaion.

```
"""
Input: db whic is a list of words
chk :  str to find
"""

def check(db,chk):
    
    seen = collections.defaultdict(list)
    for i in db:
        for j in range(len(i)):
            temp = i[:j] + "?" + i[j+1:]
            seen[temp].append(i)
            
    return len(seen[chk])
    
print check(["cat","bat"], "?at")
```

Answer (score 0):

Can I do it with ascii values like:

- for charcters in queryword calculate the ascii values sum.
- for words in dictionary, calculate ascii of words character wise and check it with ascii sum of query word, like for bat, if ascii of b matches ascii sum of queryword then increment count else calculate ascii of a and check with query ascii if not then add it to ascii of b then check and hence atlast return the count.
  How's this approach?

Answer (score 0):

**Java Implementation using Trie**

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.lang.*;

public class Main {

    static class TrieNode 
    {
        TrieNode []children = new TrieNode[26];
        boolean endOfWord;
        TrieNode() 
        { 
            this.endOfWord = false; 
            for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++) { 
                this.children[i] = null; 
            } 
        }

        void addWord(String word) 
        { 
            // Crawl pointer points the object 
            // in reference 
            TrieNode pCrawl = this; 
    
            // Traverse the given array of words 
            for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) { 
                int index = word.charAt(i) - 'a'; 
                if (pCrawl.children[index]==null) 
                    pCrawl.children[index] 
                        = new TrieNode(); 
    
                pCrawl = pCrawl.children[index]; 
            } 
            pCrawl.endOfWord = true; 
        }
        public static int ans2 = 0;
        void search(String word, boolean found, String curr_found, int pos) 
        { 
            TrieNode pCrawl = this; 
    
            if (pos == word.length()) { 
                if (pCrawl.endOfWord) { 
                    
                    found = true; 
                    ans2++;
                } 
                return; 
            } 
    
            if (word.charAt(pos) == '?') { 
    
                // Iterate over every letter and 
                // proceed further by replacing 
                // the character in place of '.' 
                for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++) { 
                    if (pCrawl.children[i] != null) { 
                     pCrawl.children[i].search(word,found,curr_found + (char)('a' + i),pos + 1); 
                    } 
                } 
            } 
            else {  // Check if pointer at character 
                // position is available, 
                // then proceed 
                if (pCrawl.children[word.charAt(pos) - 'a'] != null) { 
                    pCrawl.children[word.charAt(pos) - 'a'] 
                        .search(word,found,curr_found + word.charAt(pos),pos + 1); 
                } 
            } 
            return; 
        } 
    
        // Utility function for search operation 
        int searchUtil(String word) 
        { 
            TrieNode pCrawl = this; 
    
            boolean found = false; 
            ans2 = 0;
            pCrawl.search(word, found,"",0); 
            return ans2;
        }   
    }

    static int searchPattern(String arr[], int N,String str) 
    { 
        // Object of the class Trie 
        TrieNode obj = new TrieNode(); 
    
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) { 
            obj.addWord(arr[i]); 
        } 
    
        // Search pattern 
        return obj.searchUtil(str); 
    } 

    

    public static void ans(String []arr , int n, int m,String [] query, int q){
        

        for(int i=0;i<q;i++)
        System.out.println(searchPattern(arr,n,query[i]));


    }




    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner scn = new Scanner();
        
            int n = scn.nextInt();
            int m = scn.nextInt();
            String []arr = new String[n];

            for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
                arr[i] = scn.next();
            }
            int q = scn.nextInt();

            String []query = new String[q];

            for(int i=0;i<q;i++){
                query[i] = scn.next();
            }

            ans(arr,n,m,query,q);

        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like it was a coding challenge about https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space%E2%80%93time_tradeoff

Depending on parameters N,M,Q as well as data and query distribution, the "best" algorithm will be different. A simple example, given the query `???` you know the answer — the length of the dictionary — without any computation

In the general case, most likely, it pays to create a search index in advance (that is while reading the dictionary, before any query is seen).

I'd go with this: number the input `0 cat; 1 map; ...`

Then build a search index per letter position:

```
index = [
  {"c": 0b00001, "m": 0b00010, ...}  # first query letter
  {"a": 0b01111, "e": 0x10000}       # second query letter
]
```

Prepare `all = 0x11111` (all bits set) as "matches everything".

Then query lookup: `?a?` ⇒ `all & index[1]["a"] & all`. †

Afterwards you'll need to count number of bits set in the result.

The time complexity of single query is therefore `O(N) * (M + O(1))` ‡, which is a decent trade-off.

The entire batch is `O(N*M*Q)`.

Python (as well as es2020) supports native arbitrary precision integers, which can be elegantly used for bitmaps, as well as native dictionaries, use them :) However if the data is sparse, an adaptive or compressed bitmap such as https://pypi.org/project/roaringbitmap may perform better.

† In practice `... & index[1].get("a", 0) & ...` in case you hit a blank.

‡ Python data structure time complexity is reported O(...) *amortised worst case* while in CS O(...) *worst case* is usually considered. While the difference is subtle, it can bite even experienced developers, see e.g. https://bugs.python.org/issue13703

Answer (score 0):

One approach could be to use Python's [fnmatch](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fnmatch.html#module-fnmatch) module (for every pattern sum the matches in words):

```
import fnmatch

names = ['uqqur', 'lxzev', 'ydfgs']
patterns = ['?z???', '???i?', '???e?', '???f?', '?z???']
[sum(fnmatch.fnmatch(name, pattern) for name in names) for pattern in patterns]

# [0, 0, 1, 0, 0]
```